# Fans not working on Asus X555LJ

Tags: windows, fan, temperature, asus-laptop, speedfan

as of yesterday or so my laptop's fans stopped working with no apparent reason.

This is what appears on SpeedFan:

[image]

Open Hardware Monitor:

[image]

I also have an error on SpeedFan that I don't know the meaning of.

```
Found ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB on AdvSMART
INFO : SCSI DISABLED by user or because iaStorA.sys is installed
Found ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. X555LJ
Found ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. X555LJ
Found ACPI temperature
Found Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
End of detection
```

Is this due to a software bug or did the fans just died?

Comment: You can ignore the SpeedFan error.  You might want to run several tools to determine the fan speed, if your fan was not working, your machine would almost nearly instantaneously turn off.  I assume that isn't happening.  Your temperatures indicate there is nothing wrong with your fans.

Comment: You should also be able to *hear* the fan, though it is soft.